# Select the root element(aka key or envelope)

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

My understanding is that Retrofit and it's Gson parser expect a format of:

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

However, what if my API is wrapping everything into an attribute like:

```
{ 
    'data':[
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

How can I tell Retrofit to start parsing inner objects from within 'data'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your Retrofit interface methods return a custom type you define which itself contains a list called data.

```
public class MyResponse {
    private final List<Thing> data;
}

public interface MyApi {
    @GET("/data")
    Call<MyResponse> getThings();
}
```

This is the simplest solution. You could instead implement custom deserialization logic in a `TypeAdapter` registered with your `Gson` instance which ignores the object wrapper, but it would be more complicated and you would need to do some refactoring if the API ever returned something useful in that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks man, I was coming to the same conclusion. Coming from the web, all of these options seem overly complicated when all I want is "body.data". :)